# Studying the solution to a multidimensional Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Consider $A(t)=(a_{ij}(t))$ a real symmetric matrix $N\times N$ with continuous coefficient $a_{ij}$. Suppose that all the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ are lower than $-1$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Defined $u$ the solution to the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t(t)=A(t)u(t)\\
u(0)=u_0\in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
prove that \begin{equation}\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}|u(t)|^2=0.
\end{equation}
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the time-derivative of the scalar product $(u(t),u(t))$ and show that it is smaller than $-2(u(t),u(t))$. [You'll need to know how to estimate $(u,Au)$ in terms of eigenvalues].

Comment: Wonderful, it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, and as you have probably noted it also gives the exponential decay in time of the norm!